# Adding 3 basic features to my existing code

Tags: c

I have a gradebook program that I've been building, which works fine, but now I want to slot 3 new functions into the existing code. I can't wrap my brain around the logical path I need to take to make it work. I need a SIMPLE way to also get the highest, lowest, and average grades printed at the end. Here's my program...

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <ctype.h>    
#define MAX_GRADE_COUNT 200

int main() {
    int grade[MAX_GRADE_COUNT];
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    char continueResponse;

    printf("Welcome to Gradebooker!\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_GRADE_COUNT; i++) {
        printf("Please enter grade (0-100): ");
        scanf(" %d", &grade[i]);
        count++;
        printf("Do you have more grades to enter?(Y/N): ");
        scanf(" %c", &continueResponse);
        if(toupper(continueResponse) != 'Y') {
            printf("\n >> Thank you for using Gradebooker! <<\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nCurrent Gradebooker listings: \n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("\t%5d\n", grade[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, please don't post either images of text, or links to them. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or you'll just get downvotes and "close" requests. Tip: prepare your question in a text editor before posting. Then you won't get "lost my text" disappointments. Regarding the MCVE, when you have edited, compiled and run the code you want to post, **copy & paste** it. Finally, does your compiler work from a picture of your code? No! and ours don't either.

Comment: See ["Complete" here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here is formatting help: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: If the formatting help does not fix your problem with showing your code as text, then yes, please do type all of your text here again. If it is too long to do that, then it is not a [mcve] anyway. Or do post your code as terrible block of characters. Believe me, people here prefer that to a picture of text and some might actually help you with editing it for you into decent formatting. They will never ever with a picture of text.

Comment: I fixed it. Can you please look again?

Comment: You can add another loop after the data input which sums a total of the grades (so you can make an average after the loop), and keeps track of the highest and lowest. For example `int lowest = grade[0]; for(i = 0; i < count; i++) { if(grade[i] < lowest) { lowest = grade[i]; } }` and so on.

Comment: OT: When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values)  If the returned value does not match the number of input format specifications then an error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program would need to calculate the max, min and average in the second loop, like this:

```
int sum = 0;
int minimum = INT_MAX;
int maximum = 0;
for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("\t%5d\n", grade[i]);
    sum += grade[i];
    if(grade[i] < minimum) minimum = grade[i];
    if(grade[i] > maximum) maximum = grade[i];
}
float average = (float)sum / count;
printf("min grade: %d\n", minimum);
printf("max grade: %d\n", maximum);
printf("average: %f\n", average);
```

The minimum starts with a value that is larger than all values in the list (`INT_MAX` for example is the largest possible value an `int` can take). Then, for each grade in the array, it replaces it with that grade, if it is smaller than the one currently in the `minimum` variable. That way `minimum` will in the end contain the smallest grade.

Same for maximum, but reversed.

For the average, it accumulates the sum of all grades (`sum` needs to be initialized to 0 at the beginning), and the divides it by the number of grades in the end. This gives an arithmetic mean in `average`.

Using `float`, it calculates the average as a floating point number (so the average can be non-integer). The `(float)sum / count` is needed so that it will first cast (convert) `sum` to a float, and so a floating point division on it. Otherwise, with `sum / count` is would do an integer division (which returns a rounded down integer), and store that as float in the `average` variable afterwards.

Comment: I'm VERY new to coding. Just started this week. Can you please show me where I need to put that code, within my existing code, to make it still execute it's original function, as well as the new functions? I'm not great at freestyling just yet...

Comment: It replaces the second `for` loop (so the 3 lines from `for` to `}`.
And for the `INT_MAX` would also need a `#include <limits.h>` at the beginning, but you could also use a large value like 100 (maximal possible grade value) instead.

Comment: I'm very sorry. You did everything exactly right. I was just forgetting to add the #define INT_MAX that you included. I got it now. You're amazing, thank you very much!

Comment: @NicoleGrimes you don't `#define INT_MAX` it is defined for you, if you `#include <limits.h>`.

Comment: You don't need INT_MAX or a sentinel value. The first grade in the array is suitable to initialize both min and max. The rest of the grades will be smaller, larger, or equal to it and min and mix will adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**The idea for finding maximum value is:** first declare a variable (lets say, MAXX) to store maximum value and initial it with as minimum value as possible and then iterate through the array and if any value in the array found greater then the current value of MAXX variable than update the value of MAXX with the value.

**The idea for finding minimum value is:** first declare a variable (lets say, MINN) to store minimum value and initial it with as maximum value as possible and then iterate through the array and if any value in the array found greater then the current value of MINN variable than update the value of MINN with the value.

**Idea for finding avarage:** Sum all the grade and then divide the *sum* with the number of grade.

See the implementation below for better understanding:

```
int max_grade = 0;//for storing maximum grade
/*
Minimum possible value should be initialize here.
Best option to write here is:
int max_grade = INT_MIN; 
But to use INT_MIN <limits.h> file must be included.
*/
int min_grade = 10000000;//for storing maximum grade
/*
Maximum possible value should be initialize here.
Best option to write here is:
int min_grade = INT_MAX; 
But to use INT_MAX <limits.h> file must be included.
*/
int total_grade = 0;//for counting all the grade
for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if(grade[i] > max_grade){
        max_grade = grade[i];
    }
    if(grade[i] < min_grade){
        min_grade = grade[i];
    }
    total_grade += grade[i];
}
printf("Max grade = %d\n" max_grade);
printf("Min grade = %d\n" min_grade);
printf("Avg grade = %d\n" total_grade/count);
```

Comment: You can, and probably should, just initialize min and max with the first grade.

Comment: Yes off course, but i need <limits.h> file inclueded. hence i don't include it so i don't write it.

Comment: None of what you said made any sense to me. The first grade in the array can be used to initialize both min and max. There's no need for limits or anything complicated.

Comment: sorry mistaken to read your comment. what you say is absolutely fine. i just try to show the normal approach. thank you ninja for your added information.

Answer (score -1):

I could not see all your code (it seemed to be cut off at the bottom), however the basically procedure to get an average, max and min in C is as follows:

```
int running_total = 0;
int count_grades  = 0;
int max_so_far    = 0;
int min_so_far    = 999;
while( -1 ){ // infinite loop
    // get input (a grade)
    // if input is done, break
    count_grades++;
    running_total += iCurrentGrade; // (iCurrentGrade should be defined during input phase)
    if( iCurrentGrade > max_so_far ) max_so_far = iCurrentGrade;
    if( iCurrentGrade < min_so_far ) min_so_far = iCurrentGrade;
}
printf( "avg: %d  min: %d  max: %d\n", (int)(running_total / count_grades), min_so_far, max_so_far );
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering closeable posts and use your privileges to vote on closure until the OP comes up with an acceptable question.